# A word or 5-6 word phrase for "an aliquot can only be a member of a batch one time"

Tags: phrasing

I'm a software engineer trying to come up with a word or phrase to describe that relationship in a way that future software engineers can look at the code I've written and either understand what's going on quickly or be a Google search away.

Aliquot - a portion of a larger whole, especially a sample taken for chemical analysis or other treatment

Where I work, batches have many aliquots associated with them.

Another way would be to say "a marble can only be a member of a grouping one time".

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by, "an aliquot can only be a member of a batch one time”.  Is there some way that it *could* be a member more than one time?  Are you defining or describing?

Comment: No, and maybe I'm doing some of both? Processes get run on aliquots, so that what was there is considered a completely new/different aliquot, when a process is complete.

Comment: Perhaps "aliquots are batch-specific" (or "an aliquot is batch-specific"), or, as a modifier-noun phrase, "a batch-specific aliquot".

Comment: When you say "batches have many aliquots associated with them" are the batches physical production batches such as batches of drugs, food or paint or are they batch runs on a computer. That is are they batches within the computer system or batches within the business model that the computer system is modelling?

Comment: Even if *aliquot* is a fixed part of company culture, I'd still define it in the comments. That way others don't even have to open a browser or bust out the dictionary.

Comment: @BoldBen Batches are trays of small tubes each containing an aliquot - there can be hundreds of these tubes per batch.

Comment: @FeliniusRex I defined aliquot within my answer - was there something else you wanted defined?

Comment: An aliquot is not a very common English word and only has specific uses in a lab. It will not be clear to to a software engineer. You probably don't want to use it in software. It is not clear exactly how you're using the word but I suspect you will want to use 'batch' or 'sample' which have their very specific expected uses. The explanation that may be would make sense and be useful to the SWE is 'an aliquot is a __sample without replacement__' (if indeed that is the intended meaning).

Comment: Are you trying to say "only a member of one batch ***at a time***?"  or "***ever***"?  In other words could I take an aliquot associated with Batch1 and move it to Batch2 such that it is only ever a member of a single batch at a time or once it's associated with Batch1 it can never be reassociated with any other batch?

Comment: This seems like saying 'A plum taken from a plum pudding  will never be taken from a later pudding.' Plums are non-recyclable. Aliquots are perishables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine suggested "single-batch aliquot", which is the best phrase I've seen so far.

Answer (score 0):

So, If I understand you, a batch has many aliquots, but each aliquot is a member of only one group. Is that correct?

That would be a "[one to many relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model))"

Or do you mean something different?

Comment: Yeah, that's close, but I'm not sure that captures the "I can't use this aliquot again in any other batch". The way I understand this "one to many" is that "one batch can have many aliquots". In this case, I also want to make it clear that "one aliquot can only be part of one batch at all" vs "one aliquot may be part of multiple batches".

Comment: If this refers to a **comment** within your code, perhaps something very similar to  what you said, e.g. *An aliquot is a part of one and only one batch.* I would favor clarity over length.

Answer (score 0):

If "One aliquot can only be part of one batch at all" then the description would be "One aliquaot can only come from one single batch.

An aliquot may be sampled from or used in one batch only.  "An aliquot can only be taken or sampled from a batch once." or "An aliquot can only be used in a batch once."

An *aliquot* is contained an exact number of times in a group or batch or collection. Such as one of a dozen. You can have two eggs of a dozen but not 1.75 of them. Having divided the quantity you can only choose a discreet number of them, a number of aliquots. For your use you are restricting the choice to only one aliquot of the collection. 1/12 or 1/*X* not three or four of the batch.

Since you are referring to batches of chemicals from which you take samples the discrete number part of aliquot may not apply though the word is still used. A sample taken may not be quite an exact quantity. What you are trying to capture is the idea that the sample's nature includes where it is *from* and where it *goes*, what it might become after some process is used. Which of these two it is doing is unclear.

"One aliquot can only be part of one batch at all"
vs
"One aliquot may be part of multiple batches"

This depends on where each is going to or coming from. "One aliquot can only be ***added to*** one batch ever"  or "One aliquot can only be ***taken*** as a sample from one batch ever"

If you could fill in a bit more detail I'm sure the answer would pop up here shortly. Apart from that I would say "An aliquot can only be taken or sampled from a batch once." or "An aliquot can only be used in a batch once."

Comment: I'm not sure I'm completely understand, but my guess is that you're saying is that what I'm saying is ambiguous and, for you, the choices seem to be:
1. "One aliquot can only be part of one batch at all"
2. "One aliquot may be part of multiple batches"
I'm trying to get a short phrase or word to describe the first.

Answer (score 0):

Aliquots are grouped in batches.